# what does "Train it to fit the target concept -2 + x1 + x2 > 0." mean?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, perceptron

In machine learning what does "Train it to fit the target concept -2 + x1 + x2 > 0" mean?

is it that if x1 = 0 and x2 = 0 then -2 + 0+ 0 > 0 and since that is impossible then the output is 0?

Comment: There is a saying(joke? XD) "Machine learning is just curve fitting". In your case, let's consider the boundary of the area where -2 + x1 + x2 > 0. To me,  "train it to fit blabla" is just saying "let my model fit that boundary". In a binary classification perspective, it's "train the model to classify points (x1,x2), > 0 for class 1, and <= for class 2".

Comment: If you want to practice training such binary classifier,  you can first generate enough data points for both class. For example, (1,2), (0.1,2),(2,0.1),... for class 1, (0,0),(0,1),(1,1)...for class 2 (Typically, the labels are 0/1 or -1/+1). Then you use those data points to train your model.

Comment: This does not look like a programming question at all.